# Mistake in API 2.0 Documentation - Wrong item type for Careers Message

Tags: bug, status-completed, api-v2, documentation, inbox

On https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item the Careers Message example shows the wrong item type.

Answer (score 1):

A fix for this will go out with the next build.